# Не получается добавить товар в админке(voyager) laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Вытащил данные с базы данных и установил voyager. После установки зашел в админ панель и настроил bread. Затем зашел в продукцию и нажимая на добавить выскакивает ошибка:

> ```
> Trying to get property 'width' of non-object 
> (View: W:\domains\blog9999\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\bread\edit-add.blade.php)
> ```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста код, который по вашему мнению не работает или работает не так как нужно.

Comment: Вы с voyager ом работали? Обычно когда вытаскиваешь данные с бд и устанавливаешь voyager все сразу вставала, но сейчас незнаю на какой части есть или может ошибка.